# How to do lazy evaluation of Ruby arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code to do a check of nil in ruby. So what I want to achieve is this:
for example, if I call `get_score_value(nil,(nil-1))`. I want ruby to delay the evaluation of `nil-1` till it reaches the `get_score_value` function, instead of evaluate it before it got passed in the function. In another word, I want to pass a mathematical expression as an argument into a method. 
What is the most elegant way to do this in ruby? Thanks very much

```
def get_score_value(value,value2)
    value.nil? ? "NULL" : value2.round(2)
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I just realized this question is actually related to the topic of lazy and strict evaluation. ( the following is from this great site:
http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-and-functional-programming/

> Strict versus lazy evaluation
>
> > Strict evaluation always fully evaluates function arguments before invoking the function. Lazy evaluation does not evaluate function arguments unless their values are required to be evaluated. One use of Lazy evaluation is the performance increases due to avoiding unnecessary calculations.
> >
> > However as the following example shows, Ruby use Strict evaluation strategy:
> >
> > print length([2+1, 3*2, 1/0, 5-4])
> >     =>ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
> >
> > The third parameter of the passed array contains a division by zero operation and as Ruby is doing strict evaluation, the above snippet of code will raise an exception.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might be interested in using a Proc...

```
func = Proc.new {|n| n -1 }

def get_score_value(value, proc)
  if value.nil?
    return proc.call(0)
  end
end

p get_score_value(nil, func)
```

Your proc is like a normal method, it can still test for nil and things like that.

Or, it allows you to provide separate functions to handle those situations:

```
func1 = Proc.new {|n| n -1 }
func2 = Proc.new { "was nil" }

def check_for_nil(value, funcNil, funcNotNil)
  if value.nil?
    return funcNil.call()
  else
    return funcNotNil.call(value)
  end
end

p check_for_nil(nil, func2, func1)
p check_for_nil(1, func2, func1)
```

Also note the potential use of the `or` keyword in cases when you simply want to convert it to an empty or default type of the input (i.e. use 0 for numbers, [] for arrays, etc.)

```
def get_score_value(value)
  (value or 0).round(2)
end
```

Comment: This is really complex; he could just put the expression in a block and the `if` statement around the `yield.`

Comment: Yep it's a bit complex, but it really depends on what he's looking for. He asked about passing in an expression as an argument, thereby lambda/proc, so I just went that route on it. I was about to add a third option of using blocks, but I see you did that. So, he has 3 good options now, just depends on what he really needs.

Comment: Your solution does have the advantage of working in almost any language, while using a block will work only in Ruby and Smalltalk. :-)

Comment: Is this called lazy evaluation, or something else?

Comment: It could be considered a form of lazy evaluation, in that you can delay executing the expression until right before it's needed. But, it's really just a function pointer or lambda. Lazy evaluation tends to imply that it's lazy all the way up the stack.

Answer (score 9):

The Ruby-ish way to do this is to put your expression in your method's block and have the method execute a conditional yield.

```
def f x
  yield if x
end

x = nil
f x do 
  x - 1
end
```

Comment: +1. Was about to do this on my answer, and it was looking a bit messier.

Comment: You are leaving off the parentheses, so kinda difficult to read at first, but ya, this looks real ruby

Answer (score 2):

You can use a block:

```
def get_score_value value
  value.nil? ? "NULL" : yield
end

x = 1
puts get_score_value(x) { x-1 }  #=> 0

x = nil
puts get_score_value(x) { x-1 }  #=> "NULL"
```