# Ruby evaluates the default value in fetch even when key is found

Tags: ruby

```
h = {a: "foo"}
h.fetch(:a, h.fetch(:b))
```

yields `key not found: :b`

It seems strange that Ruby evaluates the default value even when the key is found? Is there a way around this?

*Edit:* Apparently this behavior falls under the paradigm of lazy vs eager evaluation. Nearly all imperative languages use eager evaluation, while many functional languages use lazy evaluation. However some languages, such as Python (which was before last week the only language I knew), have lazy evaluation capabilities for some operations.

Comment: In most languages, function arguments are not evaluated lazily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do lazy evaluation of Ruby arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031804/how-to-do-lazy-evaluation-of-ruby-arguments)

Comment: @CollinD: that answer is not applicable/duplicate. If `fetch` didn't accept a block/proc, you can't change it to do so.

Comment: I find it strange that you find that strange, since all methods in Ruby behave that way, and in fact all mainstream languages behave that way. What was your first language? Haskell?

Comment: Python doesn't behave that way, at least the get method for dict does not.

Comment: Even though I know next to nothing about Python, I am reasonably sure that Python is also a strict language, and that Python also does evaluate all arguments before passing them: `python3 -c 'h = {"a": "foo"}; h.get("a", print("Hello"))' # Hello`. According to you, `Hello` should not be printed, but it *is* printed, proving that `get` *does* evaluate its second argument even if the key exists. The only difference is that `get` doesn't throw an exception and instead returns `None`, but that has no bearing on whether or not the argument gets evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems strange that Ruby evaluates the default value even when the key is found? Is there a way around this?

The overwhelming majority of mainstream programming languages is *strict*, i.e. arguments are fully evaluated before being passed. The only exception is Haskell, and calling it mainstream is a bit of a stretch.

So, no, it is not really "strange", it is how (almost) every language works, and it is also how every single other method in Ruby works. *Every* method in Ruby *always* fully evaluates *all* its arguments. That is, why, for example `defined?` and `alias` cannot be methods but must be builtin language constructs.

However, there is a way to delay evaluation, so to speak, using blocks: the content of a block is only evaluated each time it is called. Thankfully, [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) does take a block, so you can just use

```
h.fetch(:a) { h.fetch(:b) }
```

Comment: also, as variant: `h.fetch(:a, h.fetch(:b, ''))` :) (I know that this is not right, but..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the computation to only run if the key is not found, you can use the alternate form of `fetch` which accepts a block:

```
h.fetch(a) { h.fetch b }
```

I didn't actually know this was the case but I had a hunch and tried it and it worked. The reason I thought to try this was that something similar can be done in other methods such as gsub, i.e.

```
  "123".gsub(/[0-9]/) { |i| i.to_i + 1 } == "234"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `||` operator instead, since it's lazy evaluated by design.

For example the following code where `Nope` is not defined does not throw an error.

```
{ a: "foo" }[:a] || Nope
```

However the fetch version will throw an error.

```
{ a: "foo" }.fetch(:a, Nope)
```

Personally I prefer how `fetch` is designed because it wont hide a bug in the default value.

However, in cases where I would rather not evaluate a default statement, then I would definitely reach for the `||` operator before doing something in a block or a lambda/proc.

Comment: `||` operator won't do the trick if the left side can return `false`. In that case you do not know if the key was found or not